# Align images using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I get these images to align horizontally instead of vertically?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grundysf/gksSy/3/)

**CSS**

```
.images {

    top: -20px;
    width: 1400px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Are they supposed to be `1400px` apart? Also, it's the child `<div />`s of the `.images` element that need to float...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.images div > img {
    float:left;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gksSy/9/)

or..

```
.images > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gksSy/8/)

Answer (score 2):

```
.images div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The problem is that your images are inside divs that stretch across the entire width of the container. Set them to display as `inline-blocks`, and they will line up without needing to `float`.

Answer (score 1):

@JoshC is right. You want to use either floats or inline block. However, there is this open question of why do you set the width of the container to 1400px in the original question.

I'm guessing that what you want is to have all the images in a single horizontal line, rather than have them wrap, which is what will happen in the examples that every has done. You say as much in the question but its not *entirely* clear if you want a single row of images or just to fill the space horizontally and then vertically as the other answers will do.

If you use the inline-block method and set the container to not wrap, you'll get a horizontal scroll

```
.images{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.images > div {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gksSy/13/ — I added some JS to to generate a lot of images so you can see what the effect is. I also added cross browser stuff for completeness sake (although I doubt the -moz one is ever likely to be necessary)

The down side of inline-block is that the spaces between the elements appears in the result. You can fix that by removing all the whitespace between the elements.

Comment: Thanks. I set the width at 1400px because not only do I want the images horizontal, but I want to place the on the bottom right of the screen. Is that the best way to position?

Comment: Not really. To position something in the bottom right is challenging. Putting it on the right can be done using the inline block I provided above and setting the .images to align right. You can then set its container to be position:relative and then absolutely position the .images to the bottom right. I've updated the example above to show it. http://jsfiddle.net/gksSy/27/

Answer (score 0):

```
.images div {
    display: inline;
}
```

or

```
.images div {
    float: left;
}
```

Depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
.images div {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `someclass` to div's containing images

```
<div class="images">
<div class="imgs" data-ot="Test 1" data-ot-background="#ffffff" data-ot-shadow-Color="rgba(0,0,0,0.1)" data-ot-border-Width="false"><img src="http://www.yamaha.com/yamahavgn/images/icon_Phone30x30.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="imgs" data-ot="Test 2" data-ot-background="#ffffff" data-ot-shadow-Color="rgba(0,0,0,0.1)" data-ot-border-Width="false"><img src="http://www.yamaha.com/yamahavgn/images/icon_Phone30x30.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="imgs" data-ot="Test 3" data-ot-background="#ffffff" data-ot-shadow-Color="rgba(0,0,0,0.1)" data-ot-border-Width="false"><img src="http://www.yamaha.com/yamahavgn/images/icon_Phone30x30.png" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

then add some css

```
.imgs{display:inline}
```